# Different android device compatibility

Tags: android, screen, compatibility

I make an ebook app in android studio but when I install it on different devices with different screen size, it has't compatibility with them.
how I can make it that has compatibility with all screens

Comment: Please edit your question and explain, **in detail**, what "it has't compatibility with them" means.

Comment: Add error or issue details you are facing in question.

Comment: I want to make my app fit to all screens size

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague. If you're having trouble with supporting different screen densities, you may have to use dp (density independent pixels) for your layout measurements.

You cna read more about this here: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html